# get_by_id and parent Key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I ever use [get_by_id](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_id) for get an entity from datastore and never use [Ancestor Paths](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Ancestor_Paths). But the complexity of my models has made it necessary. In fact Ancestor Paths solve a big problem but now when I try to `get_by_id` an entity return `None` if the entity have the parent key. This means that I need to add the parent Key:

```py
entity = MyModel.get_by_id(id)
```

This would becomes:

```py
entity = MyModel.get_by_id(id, parent=key)
```

How to build the parent Key?

edit:

At this point I prefer to leave ancestor paths and add another keyproperty.

Comment: Note Id in get_by_id is an integer.

Comment: thanks, I know it: `int(self.request.get('id'))`

Comment: I can not answer your question directly as the definition of your parent would be very dependant on the data model you have devised.  Parent in get_by_id can be a key or an entity. I assume you have read up on how to construct keys https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass

Comment: `parent()
Returns the Key of the data entity's parent entity, or None if the entity has no parent.`
If I can't get the entity because i don't know the Parent key, how can I use this method?
Note: I'm using [NDB docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities)

Comment: As I said its very dependant on your data model.  How about including some details on your model and you URL traversal scheme.  It should be obvious from this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want using entity group you can simply create a key like that:

```
key_parent = db.Key.from_path('MyModelParent', 'id_parent') # You don't have to create this kind in the datastore.

id = int(self.request.get('id'))
entity = MyModel.get_by_id(id, parent=key_parent)
```

I notice that: You use an upper case for the key parameter. It's *parent* not *Parent*.

```
entity = MyModel.get_by_id(id, Parent=key) # Wrong
entity = MyModel.get_by_id(id, parent=key)
```

Oh, you are using NDB:

```
key_parent = ndb.Key('MyModelParent', 'id_parent')
```

Comment: At the time of my question I did not know a thing: the ID of an entity is not absolutely unique. That's because before the question I ever code without parents and numeric ids. I did not understand why it was necessary to build even the parent key if the ID is unique(wrong).